# substring is counting correct characters but not showing correctly on app

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using substring to show first 45 characters of string

```
  <div className="well-Font--medium">
    {!props.customer_details[item.key] ? `${item.description.substring(0, 45)}...` : ''}
  </div>
```

when i look on App the text appears as follows

[image]

So you can see the first text (in a first draft..) is shorter than the second (In the final..) while they have same number of characters.

I tried to remove font class but no luck. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: It's most likely a unicode character issue, have you tried copying the text out and placing it in the console then running substring on it?

Comment: Regarding fonts, each character has a width including `,` , unless you are using a specific font which is designed to be a specific width for every character, these two strings absolutely will be different size even though the character count is the same. They are typically called 'fixed-width' fonts.

Answer (score 0):

All characters have a different width so you will get varying string lengths even if they have the same number of characters.

You could instead not trim the string with JavaScript and instead apply a CSS class like this:

```
.truncate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This will limit the content to a single line and truncate the text when it reaches the edge of the container, adding ... at the end.

This way you could fit as many characters as will fill the container width.